# CakePHP Error Handler

Tags: function, cakephp, private

Okay, so I had an error and CakePHP have suggested that I can create my own error message. It says I should put private_action.ctp inside the Errors folder. It was named that way because if people try to access a private function via typing the url that error will appear.

So now that I have a private_error.ctp page, how can I use it? How do I make it look like all the other pages in my website? Because for now, it just looks like the default CakePHP design.

Can someone give me an example? The cookbook is kinda complicated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create private_action.ctp file. Your debug level is greater than 0. If you set 'debug => 0' you won't see that detailed error, instead you'll get a NotFouundException.

Comment: I already made that page and when I tried accessing the private function, it appeared. So it's a customizable error message, which I have no idea how it works.

Comment: I think if you set debug => 0, all the errors will be displayed in two views that are in View/Errors folder, error400.ctp and error500.ctp. You can customize them.

Comment: I don't need to see the errors in my code per se but the error if  someone tries to do something which will trigger that error. For example: I have a private method named test() which will run if I press a button. Now, since the method is private it cannot be accessed by typing this url: localhost/appname/controller/test. And Cake's suggestion of using private_action.ctp is the solution yet I dont know how to use it.